# Switch login in j_security_check

Tags: java, tomcat, realm, j-security-check

I am using the Tomcat and my application is in GWT. Login mechanism is being managed by tomcat using `j_security_check`. Now I am able to login properly in the application.

But after login to the application when I click on any button I should be able to switch my login to the another user.

Lets say there are 3 users in table, `Admin`, `Employee`, `Viewer`. Now I logged in using `Admin`. After that I can see two buttons, `btn1`, `btn2`. On click of `btn1` my application should **automatically login** to the `Employee` user. I **should not see the Login** screen again.

In brief I need **auto login** after I logged in the appliccation passing the `j_security_check`.

How it can be done? Sorry if I am mistaken somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i found it myself. For all who are facing the same issue i am just posting here the link from where i got the solution.
[Request to j_security_check return 408 error only with right paramters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536266/request-to-j-security-check-return-408-error-only-with-right-paramters)

Thanks.